# How to produce a graphic of an extremely large graph?

Tags: graphviz

I have a Graphviz output file that is about 130mb representing a graph with a couple of hundred thousand nodes.  It is a brute force Tic-Tac-Toe state diagram.

The edges are labelled with the cumulative totals for wins by X or wins by O.

Graphvis Editor 1.02/Graphvis 2.38 for Windows are not able to load the entire file, indeed they crash when attempting 30,000 lines of the file using sfdp with overlap=false.  I had originally been using dot but the resolution was not good enough to read the text on the graph.

I am able to reduce the graph, I am not looking for an answer that explains why my graph is silly and should be reduced, I am looking to render it to a png file.

Is there a away to accomplish this with graphviz or should I use a different tool?  Would the results be better using a linux installation to obtain a 64 bit version?

Sample code:

```
digraph {
    graph [fontname = "Monospace"];
    node [fontname = "Monospace"];
    edge [fontname = "Monospace"];

    t0[label=" | | \n-+-+-\n | | \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t01[label="X| | \n-+-+-\n | | \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t0 -> t01[label="X:14652 O:7896"]
    t02[label=" |X| \n-+-+-\n | | \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t0 -> t02[label="X:14232 O:10176"]
    t03[label=" | |X\n-+-+-\n | | \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t0 -> t03[label="X:14652 O:7896"]
    t04[label=" | | \n-+-+-\nX| | \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t0 -> t04[label="X:14232 O:10176"]
    t05[label=" | | \n-+-+-\n |X| \n-+-+-\n | | \n"]
    t0 -> t05[label="X:15648 O:5616"]
    t01111111[label="X|O|X\n-+-+-\nO|X|O\n-+-+-\nX| | \n" style=filled fillcolor=yellow]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the resolution was not good enough to read the text when using dot? Was it the crossings of the edges and overlap in the edge labels? You can always force separation by adding `sep` or `overlap`. Seems to me that the hierarchical nature of dot should be the best to plot a neural network structure instead of the force layout by sfdp.

Comment: @JosepValls  I mean that the graph is exceptionally wide and is produced very zoomed out resulting in minuscule text.  Zooming in causes the text on both the nodes an edges to be rendered unreadable even at very minor zoom levels.